# Get a specific item from the return

Tags: javascript, jsom

I have some javascript which is looking to a list, it returns more than one result. I want to be able to store each result in its own object. How can I do this? Please see my code for illustration thanks.

```
var _ClientContext  = null,
    _List           = "",
    _Field          = "",
    _SiteURI        = "",
    _Item           = "";

//how we create a constructor / class in OOP JS
var SharePointStuff = function(SiteURI) {
    this._SiteURI = SiteURI; 
    this.GetSetClientContext(this._SiteURI);
}

//how we create a method in OOP JS
SharePointStuff.prototype.GetListItem = function(List, Title, Field, Caml, RetrievingSettings) {
    this._List = List;
    this._Field = Field;
    this._Title = Title;

    var SPList = this.GetSetClientContext(this.SiteURI).get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(this._List);
    var CamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    //query gets settings
    CamlQuery.set_viewXml(Caml);
    var SPListItems = SPList.getItems(CamlQuery);
    this.SPListItems = SPListItems;
    this.GetSetClientContext(this.SiteURI).load(SPListItems);
    if(RetrievingSettings)
        this.GetSetClientContext(this.SiteURI).executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.GetListItemSuccessSettings),Function.createDelegate(this,this.GetListItemFailureSettings));
    else
        this.GetSetClientContext(this.SiteURI).executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.GetListItemSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this,this.GetListItemFailure));

}

SharePointStuff.prototype.GetListItemSuccessSettings = function(sender, args) {
    //loop through settings and return them as an array
    var PSTranslationSettings = { FieldSetting: {  }, RequiredLists: {  } };
    var ItemEnumerator = this.SPListItems.getEnumerator();
    while(ItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var ListItem = ItemEnumerator.get_current();
        console.log(ListItem);
        console.log("ID: " + ListItem.get_item("ID") + " Value: " + ListItem.get_item("SettingValue"));
        PSTranslationSettings.FieldSetting["ID"] = ListItem.get_item("ID")[0];
        PSTranslationSettings.FieldSetting["SettingValue"] = ListItem.get_item("SettingValue")[0];
        PSTranslationSettings.RequiredLists["ID"] = ListItem.get_item("ID")[1];
        PSTranslationSettings.RequiredLists["SettingValue"] = ListItem.get_item("SettingValue")[1];
    }
    console.log(PSTranslationSettings);
    //return PSTranslationSettings;
}

SharePointStuff.prototype.GetListItemFailureSettings = function(sender, args) {

}


SharePointStuff.prototype.GetListItemSuccess = function(sender, args) {
    //loop through settings and return them as an array
    var ItemEnumerator = SPListItems.getEnumerator();
    while(ItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var ListItem = ItemEnumerator.get_current();
    }
}

SharePointStuff.prototype.GetListItemFailure = function(sender, args) {

}

SharePointStuff.prototype.GetSetClientContext = function(SiteURI) {
    if(this._ClientContext == null) {
        this._ClientContext = new SP.ClientContext(SiteURI);
    }
    return this._ClientContext; 
}

function TranslationSystemInit() {
//setting variables
   var SPStuff = new SharePointStuff("https://pointsolutioncouk.sharepoint.com/sites/pssuite-uat");
// var ClientContext = SharePointStuff.GetSetClientContext("SITE_URI");

       //"<ViewFields>" +
      //"<FieldRef Name='ID' />"+
      //"<FieldRef Name='SettingValue' />"+
   //"</ViewFields>"+


   var Settings = SPStuff.GetListItem("LIST","PS_TranslationSystem_LookupField","SettingValue",
   "<View>"+
    "<Query>"+
           "<Where>"+
              "<Or>"+
                 "<Eq>"+
                    "<FieldRef Name='Title' />"+
                    "<Value Type='Text'>PS_TranslationSystem_LookupField</Value>"+
                 "</Eq>"+
                 "<Eq>"+
                    "<FieldRef Name='Title' />"+
                    "<Value Type='Text'>PS_TranslationSystem_RequiredLists</Value>"+
                 "</Eq>"+
              "</Or>"+
           "</Where>"+
           "</Query>"+
       "</View>",true),
   SPFormsClasses = ["ui-accordion-header","fd_title","ui-tabs-anchor"]; //define all classes for SPForms controls
}

document.onload = SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js","SP.ClientContext",TranslationSystemInit);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array which will store each of your object, example:

```
SharePointStuff.prototype.GetListItemSuccessSettings = function(sender, args) {
    var PSTranslationSettings = new Array();    
    var ItemEnumerator = this.SPListItems.getEnumerator();
    while(ItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var ListItem = ItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var Setting = { FieldSetting: {  }, RequiredLists: {  } };
        Setting.FieldSetting["ID"] = ListItem.get_item("ID")[0];
        Setting.FieldSetting["SettingValue"] = ListItem.get_item("SettingValue")[0];
        Setting.RequiredLists["ID"] = ListItem.get_item("ID")[1];
        Setting.RequiredLists["SettingValue"] = ListItem.get_item("SettingValue")[1];
        PSTranslationSettings.push(Setting);
    }    
    return PSTranslationSettings;
}
```

Then you can loop through the `PSTranslationSettings` object to obtain each object.